# How to generate raster from vector in QGIS with resolution matching existing raster?

Tags: qgis

Is there any way to use open source tools (preferably QGIS) to rasterize a vector to create a raster with the same coordinates and resolution as an existing raster?

I know that the map size can be set using gdal_rasterize, but I'm hoping for something more precise...

Answer (score 1):

GRASS will be very helpful to you since it uses a [computational region](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) to work on :

> In computations,
>
> - raster input maps are automatically cropped/padded and rescaled (using nearest neighbour resampling) to match the current region in order to produce the output raster map or to query values.
> - **Raster output maps have their bounds and resolution equal to those of the current computational region**.
> - Vector maps are always considered completely.

So, using GRASS, you will define the region according to the existing raster

```
   g.region rast=myExistingRaster
```

(Adding *-p* option to the command will display raster properties)

And then, run the command to rasterize your vector layer :

```
   v.to.rast
```

More info on [v.to.rast command](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.rast.html) is available online.